# "Connection Refused" to namenode port on EC2 hadoop

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2

I am facing connection refused problem while connecting to namenode port on ec2.

```
ubuntu@ip-x-y-z-w:/mnt/hadoop/hadoop-1.1.2/bin$ jps
4843 NameNode
5230 JobTracker
4978 DataNode
5544 Jps
5374 TaskTracker
5125 SecondaryNameNode
```

my core-site.xml is

```
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://10.168.99.254:9000</value>
</property>
```

where 10.168.99.254 is internal IP, and x.y.z.w is the external IP.

in /etc/hosts files

```
10.168.99.254 ec2-x-y-z-w.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

When from my local machine tried to telnet

```
telnet x.y.z.w 9000
Trying x.y.z.w...
telnet: connect to address x.y.z.w: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Check your security groups. If you use the public DNS when making connections, it will resolve to private IP within the aws region, and public IP from outside (Unless you dont use default ec2 dns).

Comment: Also make sure you do not have any port or firewall related issue.

Comment: i have added port 9000 to default security group. I am using default domoin name provided by amazon to that instance that is ec2-x-y-z-w.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Comment: when I try to telnet from the machine with internal ip telenet 10.168.99.254 it says connection refused.